# ASP.NET Universal Providers - Custom session state provider is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, session-state, asp.net-webpages

I have a web project that I develop locally and deploy to Azure. I am trying to implement the ASP.NET Universal Providers so that I can store session information in my SQL database.

I have installed ASP.NET Universal Providers to my project from NuGet and added the following to my web.config file:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="1440">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="SQLConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

When I run my project, I noticed that it automatically created a new table in my database called "dbo.Sessions".  It creates this both locally on my dev machine and on my SQL Azure database.

So, that all seems great, but no records are ever created in the dbo.Sessions table and my sessions are still timing out at the default 20 minutes.

Is there something else that I need to do to get this working?

I'll also mention this, although I'm not sure if it is relevant - I am using SimpleMembership providers for my membership and roles rather than the Universal providers.

Comment: I believe I have found the solution - I was confusing session state with user authentication when they are two different things.

If I create a new session variable, it gets properly added to the SQL dbo.Sessions table and persists for my set timeout period. This does not have any effect on my authentication timeouts. In other words, Websecurity.IsAuthenticated has nothing to do with session state.

I'm attempting to add the following to my web.config as discussed here [link]http://forums.asp.net/t/1750176.aspx/1

`code`<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms timeout="120"/>
</authentication>

Comment: I have exactly same problem and environment.  User should appear in the table immediately after opening the site regardless of the usage of the session object.  Please post the answer here if you find something.